# Animated mesh doesn't move with armature

Tags: animation, mesh, armature

I am trying to make a rotating fan and everything goes well until my fan **rotator** and **frame** are unable to move along with the **motor** (armature).

The fan blades were parent to the rotator and it works well with the armature though. Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks and have a good day.

Link to my project: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hwkuazv7i394wfx/FAN.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Your object is a bit messy (for example why is your armature scaled on the Z axis?), but to quickly fix your problem, what you need to do is assigning the meshes of *rim* and *rotator.001* to the right vertex group which is Bone.001, because it's the bone that is supposed to control them.

[image]

Comment: thanks moonboots! it works and will rescale the mesh again